# Ошибка unorderable types: tuple() < int()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ошибка unorderable types: tuple() < int()

```
a=1000
y=0
while a<1000000:
    a=a+a*1,1
    y+=1
print(y)
```

Comment: В чем заключается вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас ошибка в записи десятичной дроби:

```
a=a+a*1,1
```

В языках программирования для отделения дробной части от целой вместо запятой используется точка.

Answer (score 2):

Это специфика Python, в нем есть возможность вот таким образом создать кортеж:

```
a = 1, 2, 3
```

Мы присвоили переменной `a` кортеж вида:

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

Вот этой строкой вы создали кортеж из двух элементов:

```
a=a+a*1,1
```

В итоге на второй итерации цикла `a<1000000` вы сравниваете число с кортежем, на что Python естественно реагирует ошибкой:

```
types: tuple() < int()
```